# How to testfor a donkey in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to testfor a donkey in Minecraft, but if I do \

```
/testfor @e[type=EntityHorse] {Type:2}
```

then it won't work.  The only way I can think of doing it is testing if the donkey has anything in its chest inventory, but I don't want the player to be able to assess the chest on the donkey, so would there be any way to maybe have a locked chest on a donkey?  Also, how would I testfor if the donkey was being ridden by a player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "lock" the inventory, you could summon a mule with a saddle: `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:2,Tame:0,SaddleItem:{id:329},ChestedHorse:1}`. Summoning a horse that is **not** tame and giving it a saddle will make it rideable, with an inaccessable inventory. Also, testing for a mule will work using the `/testfor @e[type=EntityHorse] {Type:2}` syntax, so you may simply have an issue with your setup. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me forever to get back to you on this. My setup must have been wrong, as now it works perfectly.... Unfortunately, I forgot what I was going to use it for :/ I'll find a use for it though. Also, would you perhaps know anyway to test for a player riding on a horse/donkey? Testing for mobs with the Riding tag doesn't seem to work, so I doubt there would be a way to testfor a player with the Riding tag (Do players even get "Riding" tags?).

Comment: @thezi3 I'm not 100% sure, but I think  ```/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @p {Riding:{id:EntityHorse}}``` should work for the nearest player in 1.8+. I haven't been able to test this yet. If not, a slightly less reliable method could be used, testing for the player's height instead: ```/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @p[y=(the ground level of your world + about 2),dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ testfor @p```. For example, I could use ```/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @p[y=64,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ testfor @p``` if the ground level was 62.